# Show that $j_2(x)=(\frac{3}{x^3} - \frac{1}{x} )\sin(x) - \frac{3}{x^2} \cos(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, special-functions, bessel-functions

I need some help proving that:
$$j_2(x)=(\frac{3}{x^3} - \frac{1}{x} )\sin(x) - \frac{3}{x^2} \cos(x)$$ where $$j_m(x)=\sqrt\frac{\pi}{2x} J_{m+\frac{1}{2}}(x)$$

and $$J_n(x)=\sum_{s=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{s}}{s!(s+n)!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2s+n}$$

After substituting $J_{2+\frac{1}{2}}(x)$ into the formula I get:

$$\sqrt\frac{\pi}{2x}\sum_{s=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{s}}{s!(s+\frac{5}{2})!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2s+\frac{5}{2}}$$ but I have absolutely no clue as to what I should do next. I know I've pretty much done nothing but I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me where I could find a proof of this or wouldn't mind showing me how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to analyse closely the denominator $s!(s+5/2)!$.

What does $(s+5/2)!$ mean anyway? It's not a factorial of
an integer, so must be interpreted via the gamma function:
$(s+5/2)!=\Gamma(s+7/2)$. Using $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$
and $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt\pi$ gives
$$(s+5/2)!=(s+5/2)(s+3/2)\cdots(1/2)\sqrt\pi
=\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot(2s+5)}{2^{s+3}}\sqrt\pi
=\frac{(2s+5)!}{2^{2s+5}(s+2)!}\sqrt\pi.$$
For $j_{5/2}(x)$ you then get something like
$$4\sum_{s=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^s(s+1)(s+2)}{(2s+5)!}x^{2s+2}$$
which ought to be convertible to a combination of sines/cosines.